# Clojure function literal with 'rest arguments' macro after 'discard' reader macro

Tags: clojure, reader-macro

I wanted a function literal in Clojure that can take any number of arguments, but doesn't actually use them.  So I've discovered `%&` ('rest arg' for function literal) and `#_` ('discard' reader macro).

But how they work together surprises me:

```
=> (macroexpand `#(... #_ %&))
(fn* [& rest__125459__125460__auto__] (...))
```

This looks like what I wanted (and seems to work in the end), but is it how the discard macro supposed to work?  The doc [says](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch):

> The form following #_ is completely skipped by the reader.

But apparently here the ignored `%&` form has a side-effect, that is it affects the function literal args list.  Should I rely on this behavior or does it look more like a bug?

Answer (score 3):

The discard reader macro `#_` is not intended to be used alone.  Here you can see it in action:

Before:

```
(println "first")
(do
  (print "second ")
  (dotimes [i 5]
    (print i " "))
  (newline))
(println "third")

first
second 0  1  2  3  4  
third
```

and after:

```
(println "first")
#_(do
    (print "second ")
    (dotimes [i 5]
      (print i " "))
    (newline))
(println "third")

first
third
```

So adding `#_` (recursively) discards everything inside the form it is applied to.

Regarding your original question of ignoring arguments, you have a few choices:

```
(mapv  #(do %& 42)        (range 3)) => [42 42 42]
(mapv   (fn [& _]   42)   (range 3)) => [42 42 42]
(mapv   (constantly 42)   (range 3)) => [42 42 42]
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what is `#_` macro for and how it behaves normally.  My question is specifically about combination of `#_ %&` and if the apparent side-effect was intended.  Maybe I should reword the question subject a little.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke too soon, probably not a bug, *maybe* it should be disallowed and give an error. But really `#_` is for discarding *forms*, and `%&` is not a form [but also a reader macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L90-L119).

So `#_%&` is just like `#_@`, `#_;` and doesn't work. The discard reader `#_` is only to be used with "real forms" like `()` or `[]` (etc)

Answer (score 0):

`#_` clause is applied only to a form. In your example, there is a space after it so it doesn't have any effect.

Prepend any list/form with `#_` to ignore it completely:

`#_(do (print 42) (/ 0 0)) ;; there won't be an error`

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter if there is a space after `#_` or not.